# get value of f:selectItems from view in bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selecteditem

i have a `selectedOneMenu` i wann like to get the value selected into my java code to do some work with this value so this my xhtml:

```
<p:selectOneMenu  id="tbName" >
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Table" itemValue=""/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{infoTable.nameTa}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and for the java code i have this:

```
public List<SelectItem> getNameTa() {
        List<SelectItem> subcat = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        try {
            ConnectionBase con = new ConnectionBase();
            TableInfo tt = new TableInfo();

            List<String> rs = tt.getTable(con, "%");
            Iterator i = rs.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                subcat.add(new SelectItem(i.next()));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }


        return subcat;

    }
```

this methode get the List of the name of my table in data base so when i select item i wanna get the value to pu it here :

```
public List<SelectItem> getFkName2() {
        List<SelectItem> subcat = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
         nameT =generatedName(); //from the selecteditem
         System.out.println("name of table choice"+nameT);

        try {

            TableInfo tt = new TableInfo();

            List<String> rs = tt.getNameCtable(con, nameT);


            Iterator i = rs.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                subcat.add(new SelectItem(i.next()));
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        return subcat;
    }
```

to used it to make other `selectOneMenu` that get the column of the name of table selected. So what should i make it and thx

Comment: Have you checked the showcase out? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add a getter/setter of String value like this "slectedName" and for the xhtml put this:

```
 <p:selectOneMenu  id="cat">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Column" itemValue="" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{infoTable.getFkName2()}" />

                                    </p:selectOneMenu>  
               <p:outputLabel value="Table :" />

               <p:selectOneMenu  id="tbName" value="#{infoTable.slectedName}"  >
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Table" itemValue="" />
                                        <f:selectItems  value="#{infoTable.nameTa}"  />
                                        <p:ajax update="cat"></p:ajax>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

I hoppe it will work for you